# How to localize a thymeleaf input type=submit object?

Tags: html, localization, thymeleaf

Is there a way to localize an `input type=submit` object using Thymeleaf?

I have this: `<input type="submit" value="Login"/>`, but if I do this: `<input type="submit" value="Login" th:text="#{msg.loginButton}"/>` then the message is printed next to the "Login" button.

If I do this: `<input type="submit" th:text="#{msg.loginButton}"/>` the message is printed next to the login button, only this time "Submit Query" is printed on the button.

I would like to solve this without changing the class of the button itself, I want it to remain an `input type=submit`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` attribute is no different than [any other attribute you can set with ThymeLeaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes).

```
<input type="submit" th:value="#{msg.loginButton}" />
```

Comment: @DebanjanB it works, I guess it works in the same way as the other Thymeleaf objects; I've tried literally everything, but it never occurred to me to put the `th` in front of the `value`